# How to add a custom PHP page in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, templates

### Details

- I already have the `.phtml` file
- The actual path = `/var/www/html/store/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/distributors.phtml`

After doing some research I found that I will have to add this

`{{block type="core/template" template="/var/www/html/store/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/distributors.phtml"}}`

Where exactly are we suppose to add this ? 
I logged in to Mogento Admin. Go to CMS > Pages > Add New Page, and the I don't know what elses to do ?

Here is my **distributors.phtml** :

[Download it](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/distributors.phtml)

OR

[View it](http://codepen.io/evoque2015/pen/azJZdO.html)

Can someone help shed the light on this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends what you want to do. The snippet you posted should look like this:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="distributors" template="page/distributors.phtml"}}
```

And it should be placed in CMS page Content area.

Comment: Thanks, I tried paste this in `{{block type="core/template" name="distributors" template="page/distributors.phtml"}}`, save and go to Preview, I don't see any effect at all. Is it because the path is wrong ?

Comment: Path is correct. Whatever is in your .phtml should show up in CMS page.

Comment: It doesn't show. See [HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/Capture.JPG). :(

Comment: Here is my [distributors.phtml](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/distributors.phtml)

Comment: Well your template has all kind of issues but let's focus on important part. Did you omit the definition of $distributors variable because currently it's undefined. There is nothing to show.

Comment: I need to use `curl` request to my other site, then I will do this `$distributors = json_decode($body, TRUE); `. I am not sure where to do that in magento.

Comment: Basically you need to create a custom module to do that, but this is getting pretty off topic now in regard to original question and we should stop here.

Comment: I agree. I'll another post on other issue and will try to as clear as possible. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LordSkeletor Adding file inside app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/   is core rewrite, during upgrade we have face issue. Shall i add my .phtml file in app/design/frontend/default/my_theme/template/page and here my .phtml file. Is this write one?